# How to disable a reactour mask when we click outside the popover the tour will not end

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2oon.png)

When we clicked the outside the popover in reactour the tour was finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the docs are saying, that the `onCklickClose` prop have:

```
onClickClose?: (clickProps: ClickProps) => void

type ClickProps = {
  setIsOpen: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Boolean>>
  setCurrentStep: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>
  currentStep: number
}
```

You have to set the open state of the provider to `false`, and not the actual prop.

```
<TourProvider 
  onClickClose={({ setCurrentStep, currentStep, steps, setIsOpen }) => {
    if (currentStep === steps.length - 1) {
      setIsOpen(false)  
    }
    setCurrentStep((s) => (s === steps.length - 1 ? 0 : s + 1))
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks It's working fine.
But the spelling will be onClickMask, not onClickClose

Comment: If you think the answear is usefull consider accepting it.